# LINQ to SQL: Data from two unrelated tables, sorting on date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, join

I have two tables `tblActionLog` and `tblLoginLog`.

This is `tblActionLog`:

```
tblActionLog
------------
ID (int)
Happened (DateTime)
...etc.
```

This is `tblLoginLog`:

```
tblLoginLog
-----------
ID (int)
LoginDate (DateTime)
...etc.
```

Now I want to have a `GridView` with information from both of these tables interleaved in eachother so that their separate date informations are sorted, e.g.:

```
LOG OF STUFF
-------------------------------
DATE        |  WHAT     
2009-09-09  | Anderson logged in.
2009-09-08  | Smith made an action.
2009-09-08  | Smith logged in.
2009-09-06  | Anna made an action.
2009-09-04  | Smith made an action.
```

I hope this makes it clear enough. I want to get all of this information in a single LINQ query (not necessarily one SQL query). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use Select() and Union() to collate the results.

```
var query = context.Logins.Where( l => l.UserID == userID )
                          .Select( l => new { Date = l.Date, What = "logged in" } )
                  .Union( context.Actions.Where( a => a.UserID == userID )
                                          .Select( a => new { Date = a.Date, What = a.Action  } ))
                  .OrderBy( r => r.Date );
```

**Note**: you may need to materialize each subquery (use ToList() or AsEnumerable()), but I think LINQ2SQL should be able to construct the UNION directly.  Also, this is completely untested - typed straight into the answer editor and I didn't check the signature of the Union method so you may need to adjust.

Comment: Could you please give me an example using my tables as shown in the question? Thanks.

Comment: Which would be better, Union or Concat?

Comment: Actually I think the only difference in the translation is whether it does a UNION or UNION ALL.  In this case it amounts to the same thing, but Concat might be a little faster if you can tolerate duplicates (or if there are none -- which may be the case here).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it....

```
(from a in dataContext.tblActionLog
 select new
 {
    Date = a.Date,
    What = a.WhatHappened
 }).Union
      (from l in dataContext.tblLoginLog
       select new 
       {
           Date = l.Date,
           What = l.WhatHappened
       }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Date);
```

Of course, you would substitute the actual name of your DataContext object, and the actual name of the column to show what happened(since that wasn't listed in your table design).