# LINQ TO Entitites : Combining Two Non Related Tables in Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have two tables:

```
Relationships (ID,   UserID,   Type,   Contact ID)   

Contacts (ID,   Name,  Address)
```

When the type is 5 in Relationship table, Contact ID is the ID in the Contacts table.

I want to get all the contacts information for a particular user

Here is what I have :

```
IEnumerable<Relationship> rels  = user.Relationships.Where(r => r.Type==5)
foreach (Relationship r in rels)
{
            contact = contactRepository.Find(r.ContactID);  // Returns Contact Object 
            Relation relation = new Relation(r, contact);   
            RelationList.Add(relation);

 }
```

Is this correct way to do this?

I have seen other post mentioning TPC. However, I did not quite understand all that and it seemed TPC only works for code first process.

Comment: There is a similar question that has an answer using Select() and Union().Check it out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940446/linq-to-sql-data-from-two-unrelated-tables-sorting-on-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user followng linq statement to get the contacts of a given userID (let's say UserID=15) by using relatonships and contacts tables:

```
var contacts=from r in Relationships
             join c in Contacts on r.ContactID equals c.ID
             where r.Type=5 and r.UserID=15
             select c;
```